# How to get environment variables of remote host

Tags: linux, environment-variables, yaml, ansible

I am having problems working with the environment variables of a remote host. For example, when I try {{ lookup('env', 'PATH') }} this returns the path of my guest machine not of the remote host.

How to pick up / change environment variables of the remote host?

my playbook :

```
---
- name : playbook
  hosts : webservers
  gather_facts: yes
  remote_user: user1
  vars:
   Path: "{{lookup('ansible_env','PATH')}}"
  roles :
 - task1
 - task2 
 - task3
```

that's return the path of my machine not the path of remote host named user1 i'm a beginner in ansible need some help . thank you in advance.

Comment: why lookup, try only with {{ ansible_env.PATH }} ----------> Path: "{{ ansible_env.PATH }}"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The behavior of the `lookup` function is [documented explicitly](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_lookups.html#using-lookups):

> plugins allow access of data in Ansible from outside sources. These plugins are evaluated on the Ansible control machine...

There is a [FAQ](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/faq.html#how-do-i-access-shell-environment-variables) regarding access to remote environment variables:

> Ansible 1.4 will also make remote environment variables available via facts in the ‘ansible_env’ variable:
>
> ```
> {{ ansible_env.SOME_VARIABLE }}
> ```

Note that remote facts (like `ansible_env`) are only available if fact gathering is enabled (which is the default behavior of ansible, but can be disabled in the config file or in your playbooks).

If you want to *modify* the environment of the remote host, you again look to [the documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_environment.html#setting-the-environment-and-working-with-proxies) which describes the `environment` directive:

> Ansible makes it easy for you to configure your environment by using the ‘environment’ keyword. Here is an example:
>
> ```
> - hosts: all
>   remote_user: root
>
>   tasks:
>
>     - apt: name=cobbler state=installed
>       environment:
>         http_proxy: http://proxy.example.com:8080
> ```

These sets an environment variable *for this specific task*.  It is not a persistent modification.

Comment: i tried to use `{{ ansible_env.PATH}}` but still return to me the same Path of my local machine . i tried to get other variable like still return emty "" or return the value of the variable if it defined in my local machine .
and i tried to discover all the ansible_env variables in the remote host with the command `ansible all -m setup ` i can't find all the variable defined in the remote host

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_lookups.html), you can't use `lookup` for remote machines, that keyword only works for the local machine.

Instead, you want to use `{{ ansible_env.PATH}}`.

Comment: i tried to use `{{ ansible_env.PATH}}` but still return to me the same Path of my local machine . i tried to get other variable like still return emty "" or return the value of the variable if it defined in my local machine .